# Equal sized child Divs

Tags: css

I have a list of products which will be either 5 or 6 (depending on the relating product)
I would like to always have the first 2 Products (views-row-1&2) on the first row, but then for the rest to fill the width of the second row.

e.g.

[--------Product 1--------] [-------Product 2-------]
[---Product 3--][---Product 4--][----Product 5--]

OR

[--------Product 1--------] [-------Product 2-------]
[Product 3] [Product 4][Product 5][Product 6]

I cannot group these into 2 groups, but each product has its own unique class. I can create any number of wrapper divs.

```
<div class="views-row-1">
<div class="views-row-2">
<div class="views-row-3">
<div class="views-row-4">
<div class="views-row-5">
```

I am using the Bootstrap framework, and this is built in Drupal.

How can I achieve this using CSS?
(If possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use Flexbox for this:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.container > div {
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:red;
  flex-grow:1;
  text-align:center;
}
.container > div:nth-child(1),
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="views-row-1">1</div>
  <div class="views-row-2">2</div>
  <div class="views-row-3">3</div>
  <div class="views-row-4">4</div>
  <div class="views-row-5">5</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="views-row-1">1</div>
  <div class="views-row-2">2</div>
  <div class="views-row-3">3</div>
  <div class="views-row-4">4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="views-row-1">1</div>
  <div class="views-row-2">2</div>
  <div class="views-row-3">3</div>
  <div class="views-row-4">4</div>
  <div class="views-row-5">5</div>
  <div class="views-row-6">6</div>
</div>
```

With bootstrap V4 you can try this:

```css
.row>div {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container  text-center">
  <div class="row flex-wrap">
    <div class="w-50">1</div>
    <div class="w-50">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row flex-wrap">
    <div class="w-50">1</div>
    <div class="w-50">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row flex-wrap">
    <div class="w-50">1</div>
    <div class="w-50">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
    <div class="col">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to add CSS for this task. Bootstrap out of the box will work.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the bootstrap framework you are using, there are usually pre-made classes available that let you devide segments of your webdesign into rows, which can be devided into columns with equal division over your width (with the added benefit of responsiveness).

```
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
```

This way you can define a row of total width 12 with two 6 elements covering the entire width, and subcolumns of (in this example) 4, each covering for 1/3.

Comment: But he cannot separate into two groups.